# Error installing Exchange 2016 about old replaced server

Tags: exchange, migration, windows-sbs-2011

We are migrating from a SBS2011 to Server 2012 R2 and Exchange 2016. Installed Server 2012 fine, trying to install Exchange 2016 and last Readiness Check is saying that we need to upgrade a server that we do not have anymore. I found two entries in DNS for the old server and deleted them and flushed but still getting same error.

The device is not on the network, cannot ping it, cannot even get a tracert reply with the device name, I am just not sure where Exchange 2016 is getting the info from, is there anywhere in Exchange 2010 that can list our old server? I think we upgraded from SBS 2008 to SBS 2011 so there must be something I am missing. 
This is the error I am getting.

Error:
All Exchange 2007 servers in the organization must be upgraded to Exchange 2010 Service Pack 3 or later. The following servers don't meet this requirement: SERVER008.
For more information, visit: http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.E16E12CoexistenceMinVersionRequirement.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to remove it using ADSI edit.  This information will be in

> Configuration\Services\Microsoft Exchange\Organization
>   Name\Administrative Groups\Your Administrative Group\Servers

If it doesn't show you Configuration, right-click the `Default Naming Context` and choose `Configuration` under `Select a well known Naming Context`.

Comment: You can confirm it's removed once you run the above procedure by opening exchange powershell and running "get-exchangeserver"